# Does the pre-order horse return at all after the epilogue?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I've just completed the story, obviously my horses were deleted as usual with the story. However, it's been maybe 20 in game days now and my preorder horse Ardennes still hasn't spawned in the valentine's stable yet.

Will it ever come back?

Answer (score 4):

No, the Ardennes war horse isn't available to you after the story.  I just looked myself - I have my other horses there but not the Ardennes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. As during the main story, the pre-order horse can only be obtained at the Valentine stable.